# Speeding up build time of an R package

Tags: r

I'm trying to make my first (personal) R package, but it's failing `R CMD check` with "lazy loading failed" after taking ~5 minutes to build. Are there options to see what is being built? I have a bunch of data sets that I don't want to export, but I do want to keep along with my data. I want to be able to iterate faster if possible.

Comment: How many datasets are in the `data/` folder of your package, and how large are they?

Comment: None, but I have quite a few in `/inst/extdata` and they are probably 10 Mb a piece.

Comment: I am eventually going to create a master data set for `data/` but I was hoping to store the raw data and build scripts in the package directory. Is there some way I can ignore the contents of a directory in making a package?

Comment: This approach has sped things up for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382030/exclude-data-sets-from-r-package-build